# Code fails only in Release build. Enabling Page Heap prevents the failure but does not detect any error

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, heap-memory, release

Win10 MXVCC++ 2022.  Some new code works in debug build but fails -- with a self-detected error, not a crash -- in release.  Using gflags, heap checking finds no error in either build. Page Heap also reports no error, but when it is enabled, the release build works right.
I expect that more detailed self-checking will reveal an actual code bug; but I wonder if anyone else has seen similar strange behavior.

Disabling code optimization does not resolve the problem.  The code has a an OpenMP parallel for loop and two critical sections; however it fails just the same with the omp directives removed.
Debug build works in all tested variations, I expected release build to do the same.